# How to detect when user begin to scroll in React native ViewpagerAndroid

Tags: react-native, scroll, android-viewpager, swipe

I have the list of view with the question form in the ViewPagerAndroid and once the user begin to drag on the view I want to validate the question form but the thing is I cannot find the proper method to detect the user begin to drag the scroll in the ViewPagerAndroid. Could you please share me any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

```
onPageScroll
onPageScrollStateChanged
onPageSelected
```

Here are the methods you can use

For more information check [ViewPagerAndroid](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/viewpagerandroid#onpagescroll)